# $ \int \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{3-x}} \cdot d x $

Tags: indefinite-integrals, radicals

I am trying to evaluate this antiderivative $$
\int \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{3-x}} \cdot d x
$$
What i have done:

$$
\begin{split}
I
 &= \int \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{3-x}} \cdot d x \\
 &= \int \frac{2+\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{3-x}}{4+x+1+4 \sqrt{x+1}-3+x} \cdot d x\\
 &= \int \frac{2+\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{3-x}}{2+2 x+4 \sqrt{x+1}} \cdot d x\\&=\int \frac{1}{1+x+2 \sqrt{x+1}} \cdot d x\\
 &\quad +\int \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2(1+x)+4 \sqrt{x+1}}\cdot d x \\
 &\quad -\int\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2(1+x)+4 \sqrt{x+1}} \cdot d x
\end{split}
$$
From this last line i can evaluate the first two antiderivatives but the last one $$\int\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2(1+x)+4 \sqrt{x+1}} \cdot dx$$ seems a bit hard for me two evaluate, i don't find the good substitution. I am opened to any suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too large for a comment in the other answer.

Let us first try to identify the correct substitution

For real calculus, we need $x+1\ge0\text{ and }3-x\ge0\iff-1\le x\le3$

$$\iff-\dfrac12-\dfrac12\le\dfrac{x-1}2\le\dfrac32-\dfrac12$$

WLOG $\dfrac{x-1}2=\cos2t, 0\le2t\le\pi\implies x=2\cos2t+1$

$\sqrt{x+1}=+(2\cos t),\sqrt{3-x}=+(2\sin t)$ as $0\le t\le\dfrac\pi2$

Finally use $(\sin t+\cos t+1)(\sin t+\cos t-1)=(\sin t+\cos t)^2-1=?$

Comment: 1) I was just asking myself how to avoid the absolute values i obtained when trying to evaluate the integral using the substitution x-1=2.cos(2t). When you specify that 0 ⩽ 2t ⩽ π , it clearly makes it easier to deal with. 2) From your last equality we deduce that (sin(t)+cos(t)+1).(sin(t)+cos(t)-1)=sin(2t). Then $$
\frac{1}{\sin (t)+\cos (t)+1}=\frac{\sin (t)+\cos (t)-1}{\sin (2 t)}
$$  (i) . As $$
\int \frac{d x}{2+\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{3-x}}=\int \frac{4 \cdot \sin (2 t) \cdot d t}{2 \cdot(\sin (t)+\cos (t)+1)}
$$ , we have from the equality (i). [A bit long for a comment]

Comment: Then from (i) we have $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{4 \cdot \sin (2 t) d t}{2(\sin (t)+\cos (t)+1)} &=\int \frac{\sin (t)+\cos (t)-1}{2 \cdot \sin (2 t)} \cdot 4 \sin (2 t) \cdot 2 t \\
&=\int\left(\frac{\sin (2 t)}{\cos (t)}+\frac{\sin (2 t)}{\sin (t)}-2\right) \cdot d t \\
&=\int(2 \cdot \sin (t)+2 \cdot \cos (t)-2) \cdot d t \\
&=-2 \cdot \cos (t)+2 \cdot \sin (t)-2 t
\end{aligned}
$$.

Comment: @MouhamadouMoustapha, Do you have any specific query?

Comment: Thus, from (i), we have $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{4 \cdot \sin (2 t) d t}{2(\sin (t)+\cos (t)+1)} &=\int \frac{\sin (t)+\cos (t)-1}{2 \cdot \sin (2 t)} \cdot 4 \sin (2 t) \cdot 2 t \\
&=\int\left(\frac{\sin (2 t)}{\cos (t)}+\frac{\sin (2 t)}{\sin (t)}-2\right) \cdot d t \\
&=\int(2 \cdot \sin (t)+2 \cdot \cos (t)-2) \cdot d t \\
&=-2 \cdot \cos (t)+2 \cdot \sin (t)-2 t
\end{aligned}
$$. It is just awesome and elegant @labbhattacharjee . And here as we know that  $$\frac{1-x}{2}$$ is between -1 and 1 we can apply him arcos to find (2t) and then (t). Lot of thanks!

Comment: No query for the moment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$x+1=(x-1)+2$$
$$3-x=2-(x-1)$$

put

$$x-1=2\cos(2t)$$
to get

$$x+1=4\cos^2(t)$$
and
$$3-x=4\sin^2(t)$$

the integrale becomes
$$\int\frac{-2\sin(2t)dt}{1+\sin(t)+\cos(t)}$$

which can be computed using the substitution
$$u=\tan(\frac t2)$$

Comment: Very useful and awesome substitution! But how could i guess that i have to make the substition x-1=2.cos(2t). Is it just a remark or there is a trick?

Comment: like when you have $\sqrt{4-x^2}$, you put $ x=2\sin(t)$ or with $\sqrt{x^2-9},$, you put $x=3\cosh(t)$.

Comment: Oowwh i see!! Here i had to see the two equalities you gave in hint. Thank you very much Abdallah. It was very instructive!

Comment: @Muruem You are welcome. Your question is a good one.

Comment: @MouhamadouMoustapha, Please find the explanation in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

**Solution without trigonometry:**

Let $u=\sqrt{x+1}$ and $v=\sqrt{3-x}$, then $u^2+v^2=4$ and $u^2-v^2=2x-2$, so $udu+vdv=0$ and $dx=udu-vdv=2udu=-2vdv$.

\begin{align*}\int\frac{dx}{2+u+v}&=\int\frac{(u+v-2)dx}{(u+v)^2-4}=
\int\frac{(u+v-2)dx}{2uv}=\int\left(\frac{dx}{2v}+\frac{dx}{2u}-\frac{dx}{uv}\right)\\&=\int\left(-dv+du-\frac{dx}{uv}\right)=-v+u-\int\frac{du}{v}+\int\frac{dv}{u}\\&=-v+u-\int\frac{(u^2+v^2)du}{4v}+\int\frac{(u^2+v^2)dv}{4u}\\&=-v+u+\int\frac{v(udv-vdu)}{4v}+\int\frac{u(udv-vdu)}{4u}\\&=-v+u+\frac12\int(udv-vdu)=-v+u+2\int\frac{udv-vdu}{u^2+v^2}\\&=-v+u+2\int\frac{u^2d(v/u)}{u^2+v^2}=-v+u+2\arctan(v/u)+C.\end{align*}